# IOS SwiftUI Reconnect TCP Connection

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, tcp, swiftui

i create a TCP Server in C and i want a communication between an Iphone and PC.
That work. But when i close the Server or connection lost i must restart the APP on Iphone to make a new connection a simple start() don´t work, the error ist, "Cannot set state changed handler after cancel".

The second problem is, i create two Textfields for IP Adress and Port, how can i give this values to my network class and make new connection?

Thanks for help, here ist my code:

RMTApp.swift

```
//
//  RMTApp.swift
//  RMT
//
//  Created by Erik on 13.07.21.
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct RMTApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  RMT
//
//  Created by Erik on 13.07.21.
//

import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class State_button: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var strg_value: String = ""
    @Published var temp_cnt: Int32 = 0
    
    func requst_notification()
    {
       
        
    }
    func test()
    {
    
        
    }
    func button_connect()
    {
        strg_value = "Verbinden..."
    }
    func button_disconnect()
    {
        strg_value = ""
        
    }
    func counter()
    {
        temp_cnt = temp_cnt + 1;
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var IP_ADRESS: String = "192.168.5.1"
    @State private var PORT: String = "1234"
    @ObservedObject var state_button = State_button()
    @StateObject var network = Network(hostName: "192.168.178.28", port: 1234)
    @State private var switch_connect = false
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State private var textfield: String = "Du bist ein String"
    let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()

    var body: some View {
        Color.black
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(
                VStack()
                {
                    HStack
                    {
                        Image("AG")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
                        
                        
                        Text("  TCP TEST   ")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding()
                            //.padding(.bottom, 50)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        //.border(Color.white, width: 5)
                        
                        Image("AG")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
                    }
                    
                    HStack
                    {
                        Group
                        {
                        TextField("IP Adress", text: $IP_ADRESS)
                        {
                            isEditing in
                            self.isEditing = isEditing
                        }
                        onCommit:
                        {
                            print("Eingegeben: \(IP_ADRESS)")
                            self.generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
                        }
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .border(Color.white)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        //Text(test)
                         //   .foregroundColor(isEditing ? .red : .blue)
                        
                        TextField("Port", text: $PORT)
                        {
                            isEditing in
                            self.isEditing = isEditing
                        }
                        onCommit:
                        {
                            print("Eingegeben: \(PORT)")
                            self.generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
                        }
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .border(Color.white)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        //Text(test)
                         //   .foregroundColor(isEditing ? .red : .blue)
                                            
                    }//VSTACK EA field
                    }//Group
                    Toggle("Verbinden", isOn: $switch_connect)
                       .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                       .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: network.connection_status ? Color.green : Color.red))
                       .padding(6)
                       //.position(x: 180, y: 60)
                       .border(Color.white, width: 1)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
                        .onChange(of: switch_connect)
                       { value in
                           self.generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
                           if switch_connect
                           {
                               if network.connection_status == false
                               {
                                   network.start()
                               }
                           }
                           else {  }
                           //network.start()
                       }
                   
                    Text("Empfangen:")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
                    
                    ScrollView()
                    {
                        VStack()
                        {
 
                            Text(String(network.textstorage))
                             .lineLimit(nil)
                                //printf("Item \($0)")
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    .border(Color.blue)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 15, design: .default))
                    .lineLimit(5)
                    //.multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action:{
                        let vibrate = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                        vibrate.impactOccurred()
                        network.stop()
                        network.start()
                    })
                    {
                            Text("Test")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black
                                )
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 100) //right
                    .padding(.leading, 100) //left
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.blue))
                    
                    HStack
                    {
                        Button(action:{
                                network.cc()
                                let testx = " DasIstEinTest"
                                self.network.rec_val_state = false
                                if network.textstorage.count > 50
                                {
                                    for _ in 1...testx.count
                                    {
                                        network.textstorage.remove(at: network.textstorage.startIndex)
                                    }

                                }
                                network.textstorage = network.textstorage + testx;
                                let vibrate = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                                vibrate.impactOccurred() })
                    {
                            Text("Verbinden")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black
                                )
                               .padding(5)
                               .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                               .cornerRadius(5)
                               .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.green))
                                //.position(x: 60, y: 100)
                        
                    }
                        
                    //.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle());
                    
                        Button(action:{network.textstorage = "";
                            self.network.rec_val_state = false;
                            let vibrate = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                            vibrate.impactOccurred()
                            network.stop()
                        })
                    {
                            Text("Löschen")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black
                                )
                    } //Button disconnect
                    .padding(5)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.red))
                    //.position(x: 30, y: 100)
                        
                        Button(action:{ network.send(line: "Was geht ab??");
                            let vibrate = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                            vibrate.impactOccurred()
                        })
                        {
                                Text("Test")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black
                                    )
                        }
                        .padding(5)
                        .padding(.trailing, 35) //right
                        .padding(.leading, 35) //left
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .cornerRadius(0)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.blue))
                        //.position(x: 30, y: 100)
            
                    }//HSTACK
                }//VSTACK
            
            )//Color Black
    }//body view
}//Struct

 

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Network.swift

```
//
//  Network.swift
//  RMT
//
//  Created by Erik on 15.07.21.
//
import Foundation
import Network

class Network : ObservableObject {

    init(hostName: String, port: Int) {
        let host = NWEndpoint.Host(hostName)
        let port = NWEndpoint.Port("\(port)")!
        self.connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: port, using: .tcp)
    }

    var connection: NWConnection
    var rec_val : String = "" //Rec Network Data
    var textstorage : String = "" //Saves complete Network Data
    let textstorage_max : Int = 250 //Max size of textStorage
    @Published var rec_val_state = false //Variable set when Data is aviable to show on view
    @Published var connection_status = false //When connect true else false
    var IP_ADRESS : String = "192.168.178.28"

    func start() {
        NSLog("will start")
        self.connection.stateUpdateHandler = self.didChange(state:)
        self.startReceive()
        self.connection.start(queue: .main)
    }

    func stop() {
        self.connection.cancel()
        NSLog("did stop")
    }
    
    func cc()
    {
        print("XTREAME")
        self.connection = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host(IP_ADRESS), port: 1234, using: .tcp)
        //self.connection.restart()
    }
    

    private func didChange(state: NWConnection.State) {
        switch state {
        case .setup:
            break
        case .waiting(let error):
            NSLog("is waiting: %@", "\(error)")
        case .preparing:
            break
        case .ready:
            connection_status = true
            break
        case .failed(let error):
            NSLog("did fail, error: %@", "\(error)")
            connection_status = false
            self.stop()
        case .cancelled:
            NSLog("was cancelled")
            connection_status = false
            self.stop()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }

    private func startReceive() {
        self.connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65536) { data, _, isDone, error in
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                self.rec_val = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                
                if self.textstorage.count > self.textstorage_max
                {
                    for _ in 1...self.rec_val.count
                    {
                        self.textstorage.remove(at: self.textstorage.startIndex)
                    }

                }
                self.textstorage = self.textstorage + self.rec_val   
                self.rec_val_state = true
                print(self.rec_val)
            }
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("did receive, error: %@", "\(error)")
                self.stop()
                return
            }
            if isDone {
                NSLog("did receive, EOF")
                self.stop()
                return
            }
            self.startReceive()
        }
    }

    func send(line: String) {
        let data = Data("\(line)\r\n".utf8)
        self.connection.send(content: data, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed { error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("did send, error: %@", "\(error)")
                self.stop()
            } else {
                NSLog("did send, data: %@", data as NSData)
            }
        })
    }

    static func run() -> Never {
        let m = Network(hostName: "192.168.5.1", port: 1234)
        m.start()

        let t = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
        var counter = 20
        t.setEventHandler {
            m.send(line: "\(counter) bottles of beer on the wall.")
            counter -= 1
            if counter == 0 {
                m.stop()
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
            }
        }
        t.schedule(wallDeadline: .now() + 1.0, repeating: 1.0)
        t.activate()

        dispatchMain()
    }
}
```

Greetings!

Comment: Too much code, too many questions. Please ask only one question at a time and try to minimize the amount of code to only the parts that are relevant for the question.